# More RAM when I use two screens? 

Tags: memory, macbook

So, is there any possible that my Macbook use more ram when I use two screens?

First - in MB, second - Cinema Display. Also when I use only Cinema Display, MB used little less ram. Am I crazy?

Answer (score 4):

It's not hard to imagine that software has to perform additional calculations when there are more than one screen. Positions of windows, mouse pointer and more!

Since you claim the increase is in the "megabytes", it kind of fits the bill.

Answer (score 2):

Not crazy at all. All that extra data has to be stored somewhere, even if it is just a million pixels or so. I've even met some graphics cards that really don't like two screens at all. It's not that they're out of RAM, or my system is out of RAM, it just gets handled inefficiently. I would reckon to bet that you'll see performance changes across the board when hooking up that second screen, though likely nothing truly significant.